# Determine string assignment operator exception that may occur

Tags: c#, string, exception, crash, operator-keyword

I am currently learning the correct usage of try, switch, exceptions in c# and i aks myself if a exceptions can be thrown at the = operator.

I googled some and found https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs
this should be the implementation for the string class but i could not find the =operator definition in this code. Where can i find my own string.cs class implementation on my own system? I only found this online version.

```cs
string line = Console.ReadLine();
//Console.ReadLine() can throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException,
//OutOfMemoryException or IOException.
//but what can the = operator throw?

//what will happen in the following code?
string l = "Very Very extreme long long text";
```

How to handle that 100 % correct?

Comment: `=` isn't an overloadable operator. The `=` operator can cause implicit user-defined conversions to take place, which could throw exceptions, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: how is the = operator internally defined? The Systems knows what string s = "str"; means

Comment: The `=` operator always either just copies a value to a variable, or invokes a property setter or an indexer. It's not defined on a per-type basis.

Comment: ok. i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436101/create-custom-string-class . You can do it with implicit Conversation but it is in many cases not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can't get an exception from the code you wrote.

But perhaps the Console.ReadLine can raise an exception if some I/O or kernel bug occurs.

For the string assignment, I don't think that something else than an out of memory or a memory overflow or a process corruption can occurs and in this case you will lost all control of the application that will crash and perhaps you could get a BSOD or a thing like that. Nowadays it would be very very rare, on a PC even on a smartphone. Perhaps on a mini embedded system.

You don't need to try catch such things.

But to be scrupulous, you can try catch the assignments if you want, but it's a loss.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment itself cannot throw an exception, but conversions, indexers, property getters and setter or member accesses which are involved can. But this most likely means that you have a programming error that you must fix.

You should only do exception handling for true runtime problems. Mostly I/O related stuff, but also APIs that are designed to throw on certain conditions. Don't do exception handling for programming errors!

The assignment operator cannot be overloaded.

---

An example for a programming error is

```
int[] array = GetArray();
for (int i = 1; i <= array.Length; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}
```

It will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because the index range goes from `0` to `array.Length - 1`.

Correct code:

```
int[] array = GetArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { // Note: starting at 0 and using < instead of <=
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}
```

---

An example where you might get an exception with a correct code is

```
File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
```

The file could be locked by another application or the drive not be attached or you might not have enough permissions etc.

Here a `try-catch` is appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the answer! What do you mean by programming error? What if my program needs a large list and tries to allocate new memory from my System that my System do not have. There will be thrown an OutofMemoryException that i should catch.

How is the = operator internally in the string class defined?

Comment: Programming error is for instance when an index is out of bounds or if you get a `NullReferenceException`. Because then, your code is not correct. An `OutOfMemoryException` is fatal. There is nothing you can do about it, except if it results from a non-ending recursion, for instance. But then, you have a programming error again. An assignment does not generate a `OutOfMemoryException`, but an object creation can: `x = new SomeObject();`

Comment: Why is the OutOfMemoryException so fatal? I could catch this and handle it.

Comment: Well, there are cases where you can catch it. For instance, if you try to create a huge array, you might get a `OutOfMemoryException`. Then try to create a smaller one. But usually, you just won't have enough memory for what you are attempting to do. So it is mostly an incurable condition.

Comment: the example with the huge array is good. I had the same in mind. So i create a huge array that causes an OutOfMemoryException and I catch these Exception and delete this Array to have Memory in order to create a tinier one that will not cause an OutOfMemoryException.
Why do you say is this a problem?